# Gradle dependencies: What's the difference between compile project and compile name?

Tags: android, gradle

Sample code

```
dependencies {    
    compile project (':aProject')
    compile name: 'somefile'
    compile files('libs/something_local.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

My questions are

1. What's the difference between `compile project` and `compile name` here?
2. Is `compile name` the same as `compile files`?
3. When do you use `compile` directly as shown in the 5th line of code
4. What does `compile` do here? Is it compiling the files inside bracket/single quotes? Can I use something like 'build' etc.?

Answer (score 6):

Compile means, it is compiling the library in other to be used on your project

**compile project (':aProject')**

- It compiles the **module** from your project

**compile files('libs/something_local.jar')**

- It compiles a file from your project (usually it is on *lib* directory)

**compile name: 'something_local'**

**compile(name:'something_local', ext:'jar')**

- It is the same as compile files, but your are indicating the directory of the file the repositories (like compiling from a remote repository but it is from local)

**compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'**

- It compiles the library from a maven repository, you use this instead of cloning the library project and putting it to your project.